# Boolean integer display in serialize php

Tags: php, serialization

Why is it that after I save the serialization data it gives me an boolean output the results of my input is `b:1?` Below are the data that has been saved in my database.

```
a:2:{s:30:"features_safety_number_airbags";b:1;s:29:"features_safety_trans_control";b:1;}
```

This is the insert code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $add_item_features = array(
            "features_safety_number_airbags" => isset($_POST['safety_airbags']),
            "features_safety_trans_control" => isset($_POST['safety_traction']),
            );

        $add_item_features_serialize = serialize($add_item_features);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO item_newcar_temp(`item_features`) VALUES ('".$add_item_features_serialize."')";
```

Comment: I try to use strpilashes..not work on me.. I'm just a beginner..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you're actually setting the array value to the return of the `isset()` function, which is a boolean.

```
var_dump(isset($a)); // will return boolean(true/false)
```

What you want is a [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), that would look like this:

```
$add_item_features = array(
    "features_safety_number_airbags" => ((isset($_POST['safety_airbags'])) ? $_POST['safety_airbags'] : 'it wasnt set..'),
    "features_safety_trans_control" => ((isset($_POST['safety_traction'])) ? $_POST['safety_traction'] : 'it wasnt set..'),
);
```

Which will return a serialized item that looks similar to:

```
a:2:{s:30:"features_safety_number_airbags";s:14:"it wasnt set..";s:29:"features_safety_trans_control";s:14:"it wasnt set..";}
```

[**Demo/Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#0XPifiMnl)

Comment: thank you sir..this save my time...however they give me an minus votes on this..I dont know what the reason...